# How to filter date range using vue js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm learning about vue.js, and I'm trying out a filter feature using range date. The scenario is: first filter by type, then filter by date range (there are start and end dates). The results will appear when the end date is selected. I have created the first filter, which is type, and it works. I have searched various ways for the date range, but still can't find the right one. How do I filter date ranges using `computed` or `methods`? If anyone knows, can you please tell me step by step?

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    selectedType: '',
    startDate:null,
    endDate:null,
    items: [
      {
        name: 'Nolan',
        type: 'mercedes',
        year: '2020',
        country: 'england',
        date: '08/01/2020'
      },
      {
        name: 'Edgar',
        type: 'bmw',
        year: '2020',
        country:'belgium',
        date: '08/11/2020'
      },
      {
        name: 'John',
        type: 'bmw',
        year: '2019',
        country: 'england',
        date: '08/21/2020'
      },
      {
        name: 'Axel',
        type: 'mercedes',
        year: '2020',
        country: 'england',
        date: '08/01/2020'
      }
    ]
  },
  computed: {
    filterItem: function () {
      
      let filterType = this.selectedType
      if (!filterType) return this.items;  // when filterType not selected

      let startDate = this.startDate && new Date(this.startDate);
      let endDate = this.endDate && new Date(this.endDate);
      
      return this.items.filter(item => {
        return item.type == filterType;
      }).filter(item => {
        const itemDate = new Date(item.date)
        if (startDate && endDate) {
          return startDate <= itemDate && itemDate <= endDate;
        }
        if (startDate && !endDate) {
          return startDate <= itemDate;
        }
        if (!startDate && endDate) {
          return itemDate <= endDate;
        }
        return true;  // when neither startDate nor endDate selected
      })
      
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.list-item {
  margin-top: 50px;
}

#app {
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 200px;
}

span {
  margin: 0 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.filter-box {
  margin-top: 15px;
}

.card {
  box-shadow: 0px 10px 16px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16);
  width: 400px;
  padding: 20px 30px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

button {
  background-color: #1cf478;
  border: none;
  padding: 10px 25px;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-radius: 15px;
}

select,input {
  border: none;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  background-color: #c1c1c1;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <label for="">Type</label>
  <select v-model="selectedType">
    <option value="" disabled selected hidden>Type</option>
    <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
    <option value="bmw">BMW</option>
  </select>
  
  <label for="">From</label>
  <input type="date" v-model="startDate">
  
  <label for="">To</label>
  <input type="date" v-model="endDate">
  
  <div class="list-item" v-for="item in filterItem">
    <div class="card">
      <p>Name: {{ item.name }}</p>
      <p>Car: {{ item.type }}</p>
      <p>Date: {{ item.date }}</p>
      <p>Country: {{ item.country }}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How you tried to implement the data filter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's how you could fix it:

1. Create `startDate` and `endDate` as `Date`s. However, note that the date picker uses ISO string format (`yyyy-mm-dd`), which is UTC. The data contains locale specific dates (`mm/dd/yyyy`), so `Date` parses the string with local time zone. We need to normalize the dates so we're comparing dates with the same time zone offset (local preferred):

   ```js
   methods: {
     localizeDate(date) {
       if (!date || !date.includes('-')) return date
       const [yyyy, mm, dd] = date.split('-')
       return new Date(`${mm}/${dd}/${yyyy}`)
     }
   }
   ```

   ```js
   let startDate = this.localizeDate(this.startDate);
   let endDate = this.localizeDate(this.endDate);
   ```
2. The date comparisons in your `if`-`else` is explicitly checking for `null`, but their values wouldn't be `null` since you're instantiating `Date` objects. With the update in step 1, the date values are either `Date` or `false`, so you could update your comparisons to check for a falsy value instead of `null`:

   ```js
   if (startDate && endDate) {/*...*/}
   if (startDate && !endDate) {/*...*/}
   if (!startDate && endDate) {/*...*/}
   ```
3. `selectedType` is never `null`, but you can check if it's falsy to determine if the type is unspecified. In that case, you could just return the original array to avoid the unnecessary call to `Array.prototype.filter`:

   ```js
   const itemsByType = filterType ? this.items.filter(item => item.type === filterType) : this.items
   ```
4. Since you want to display the date as `MMM dd, yyyy`, you could use the *"long" date style* of [`Intl.DateTimeFormat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat) in a component method, and invoke it from the template:

   ```js
   methods: {
     formatDate(date) {
       return new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US', { dateStyle: 'long' }).format(new Date(date))
     }
   }
   ```

   ```html
   <p>Date: {{ formatDate(item.date) }}</p>
   ```

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    selectedType: '',
    startDate:null,
    endDate:null,
    items: [
      {
        name: 'Nolan',
        type: 'mercedes',
        year: '2020',
        country: 'england',
        date: '08/01/2020'
      },
      {
        name: 'Edgar',
        type: 'bmw',
        year: '2020',
        country:'belgium',
        date: '08/11/2020'
      },
      {
        name: 'John',
        type: 'bmw',
        year: '2019',
        country: 'england',
        date: '08/21/2020'
      },
      {
        name: 'Axel',
        type: 'mercedes',
        year: '2020',
        country: 'england',
        date: '08/01/2020'
      }
    ]
  },
  computed: {
    filterItem() {
      let filterType = this.selectedType;
      let startDate = this.localizeDate(this.startDate);
      let endDate = this.localizeDate(this.endDate);
      
      const itemsByType = filterType ? this.items.filter(item => item.type === filterType) : this.items
      return itemsByType
        .filter(item => {
          const itemDate = new Date(item.date)
          if (startDate && endDate) {
            return startDate <= itemDate && itemDate <= endDate;
          }
          if (startDate && !endDate) {
            return startDate <= itemDate;
          }
          if (!startDate && endDate) {
            return itemDate <= endDate;
          }
          return true;
        })
    }
  },
  methods: {
    localizeDate(date) {
      // Date picker uses ISO format (yyyy-mm-dd), which is UTC. The data
      // contains locale specific date strings (mm/dd/yyyy), which `Date`
      // parses with local time-zone offset instead of UTC. Normalize the
      // ISO date so we're comparing local times.
      if (!date || !date.includes('-')) return date
      const [yyyy, mm, dd] = date.split('-')
      return new Date(`${mm}/${dd}/${yyyy}`)
    },
    formatDate(date) {
      return new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US', { dateStyle: 'long' }).format(new Date(date))
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.list-item {
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.card {
  box-shadow: 0px 10px 16px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16);
  width: 400px;
  padding: 20px 30px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

select,input {
  border: none;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  background-color: #c1c1c1;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <label for="">Type</label>
  <select v-model="selectedType">
    <option value="" disabled selected hidden>Type</option>
    <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
    <option value="bmw">BMW</option>
  </select>
  
  <label for="">From</label>
  <input type="date" v-model="startDate">
  
  <label for="">To</label>
  <input type="date" v-model="endDate">
  
  <div class="list-item" v-for="item in filterItem">
    <div class="card">
      <p>Name: {{ item.name }}</p>
      <p>Car: {{ item.type }}</p>
      <p>Date: {{ formatDate(item.date) }}</p>
      <p>Country: {{ item.country }}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

This question is more about js, not vuejs. Use Date type, not string type for date data. It is comparable, for example, `new Date('2020-01-01') < new Date('2020-01-02')` is `true`

```js
  computed: {
    filterItem: function () {
      const filterType = this.selectedType  // string or null
      const startDate = this.startDate;    // Date or null
      const endDate = this.endDate;  // Date or null
      
      return this.items.filter(item => {
        if (filterType === null) return true;  // when filterType not selected
        return item.type == filterType;
      }).filter(item => {
        const itemDate = new Date(item.date)
        if (startDate !== null && endDate !== null)) {
          return startDate <= itemDate && itemDate <= endDate;
        }
        if (startDate !== null && endDate === null) {
          return startDate <= itemDate;
        }
        if (startDate === null && endDate !== null) {
          return                          itemDate <= endDate;
        }
        return true;  // when neither startDate nor endDate selected
      })
    }
```

Comment: i've edited my post, and adding your code there. but it doesn't work

Comment: Did you get error on console? I guess startDate and endDate willl be string, not Date. You might need to cast.